# how to extract links from multiple divs with the same class name with xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, href

I am working on a selenium project. I have a web page with multiple `divs` with the same class name such as this

```
<div class="usr_blk hid">...</div>
<div class="usr_blk hid">...</div>
<div class="usr_blk hid">...</div>
<div class="usr_blk hid">...</div>
<div class="usr_blk hid">...</div>
<div class="usr_blk hid">...</div>
<div class="usr_blk hid">...</div>
<div class="usr_blk hid">...</div>
<div class="usr_blk hid">...</div>
```

inside each div is the following content

```
<div class="usr_blk hid">
    <div class="image_info">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="the link I want to scrape">Link</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract the `link` from the `a tag` inside each `div`. This is what I tried so far

```
list_xpath = "//div[@class='usr_blk hid']//div[@class='image_info']//a"
list_raw = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(list_xpath)
lst = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in list_raw]
```

But this results in an empty list. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

#### I cannot share the website link with you because of company policy.

Comment: Simplify. First, try find_element_by_css_selector('div.usr_blk.hid').

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Should I try `find_elements_by_css_selector` as there are multiple divs

Comment: @Sashaank You've tried use `WebDriverWait`?

Comment: Oh yes. Missed the s.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel wouldnt `WebDriverWait` only find the first div with the given class name? I want the code to find all the divs

Comment: Simplify by first finding all the enclosing divs then loop to find the inner divs then find whatever it was you were searching for. Don't try to do it all in one line of code. Oh and I did not mention waiting but that may be a good idea.

Comment: Are you sure about this line `<div class="image_info>`? It should be `<div class="image_info">`; if it's not a typo in the question but in the page itself, it may explain the problem.

Comment: @JackFleeting it's a typo. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `WebDriverWait`.

`.visibility_of_all_elements_located` return a list of web element:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
list_raw = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 'your_xpath')))
```

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```